# CosmoDb with Robomongo cant see document id's?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, robo3t

Can anyone tell me why when I use DataExplorer for CosmoDb DB I get the following:

```
{
    "id": "d502b51a-e70a-40f1-9285-3861880b8d90",
    "Version": 1,
    ... 
}
```

But when I use Robomongo I get:

```
{
    "Version" : 1,
    ...
}
```

minus the id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried to repro your scenario but it all worked correctly.

The Mongo document in Portal Data Explorer:

[image: Render in Data Explorer]

The Mongo document in Robo 3T:

[image: Render in Robo 3T]

They both have the `id` property.

Are you applying Projections on Robomongo / Robo 3T?

Comment: Right so following what you did I was able to get the id to return if the API db was initially setup for MongoDB. This DB I was working with was setup for SQL and looks like I cannot view the id's. Which kind of limits me ... sigh.

Comment: I'd recommend contacting [askcosmosdb@microsoft.com] directly as they may be able to provide options for migrating your SQL API db to a Mongo API db.

Comment: @FarmBoy If its a SQL account, might want to try with SQL-api oriented tools like [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-cosmos-db-in-azure-storage-explorer-preview/). I believe Robomongo uses the MongoDB wire protocol which matches MongoDB API accounts.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment cosmodb works separately SQL API and Mongo API, each one has different implementation, SQL API use **JSON** and Mongo use **BSON**, you need to be clear this while you are creating the document.

If you create the document with a **BSON-based** tool like Robo3t for example, you are going to get something like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5be0d98b9cdcce3c6ce0f6b8"
    },
    "name": "Name",
    "id": "5be0d98b9cdcce3c6ce0f6b8",
    ...
}
```

Instead, if you create your document with **JSON-based** like Data Explorer, you are going to get this:

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "id": "6c5c05b4-dfce-32a5-0779-e30821e6c510",
    ...
}
```

As you can see, **BSON-based** needs that `_id` and inside `$oid` be implemented to works right, while **JSON-based** only `id` is required. So, you need to add the properties while you save the document (see below) or open it with the right tool, as [Matias Quaranta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641598) recommend, use **[Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-cosmos-db-in-azure-storage-explorer-preview/)** or even **Data Explorer** to get both protocols properly.

Also, if you use a system to create the document and you want to use BSON format, You need to add the $oid, for example in core net is something like this:

```
public bool TryGetMemberSerializationInfo(string memberName, out BsonSerializationInfo serializationInfo)
{
    switch (memberName)
    {
        case "Id":
            serializationInfo = new BsonSerializationInfo("_id", new ObjectIdSerializer(), typeof(ObjectId));
            return true;
        case "Name":
            serializationInfo = new BsonSerializationInfo("name", new StringSerializer(), typeof(string));
            return true;
        default:
            serializationInfo = null;
            return false;
    }
}
```